# nested div parent overlapping child when window resize

Tags: css, resize, overlapping, html

When resizing browser window the content div overlaps the logo div is. is there any solution for this. I want the logo to resize when window is resized.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    height:74%;
    background-color:#7d6961;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    top: 10%;
}

#logo {
    background-image:url(logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    left: 9%;
    top: 5%;
    right: 2%;
    bottom: 21%;
    width: 77%;
    height: 65%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the resize-callback from the window-DOM Object.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var _width = $(window).width(),
        _height = $(window).height();

    console.log('width: ' + _width);
    console.log('height: ' + _height );
});​
```

Checkout this jsfiddle for an implementation example (I put the logo into an img-Tag, so it is always fully visible):
http://jsfiddle.net/qY3kM/

Dynamic resizing of images purely by css is not possible (afaik...maybe by using css-expressions, but they are ugly and should not be used at all.). There are also jquery plugins for dynamic resizing, but I never used one, so I cannot recommend one.

Comment: you're welcome. One more or less unrelated thing about logos: I'd suggest to put company logos always as an <img>-Tag, so they are printed. Logos which are put in the page via css background are mostly not printed (it's the default setting of most browsers to not print css-backgrounds).